# Jenkins - Show "Advanced" job parameters from drop down / advanced button

Tags: jenkins, plugins, hudson-plugins

I have a Jenkins job where some parameters are optional but if they are changed they can fail the job almost instantly.
I added useful information next to each parameter, wrote "DO NOT CHANGE" next to those which are sensitive and even explained to the users to don't touch anything unless they know what they are doing. Unfortunately, that doesn't help; People are still changing values and the job fails.
Hiding the parameters completely (for example, with the use of the "Hidden Parameter plugin") is not an option because I still want to give access to the more advanced users, but keep the everyday users away. 
Is there a way to hide the advanced parameters (by use of a drop down ["Basic/Advanced"] or maybe an "Advanced..." button that'll show the parameters?

Comment: were you able to find a solution?